# How to start up the code i found in a git repo

Tags: node.js

I have this code i found on a git repo i want to work on, but cant get it started am currently left with this error when i run node index, on the terminal

throw new Error(`Config validation error: ${error.message}`);
^

Error: Config validation error: child "JWT_SECRET" fails because ["JWT_SECRET" is required]

this is the link to the repo https://github.com/lowewenzel/bet
thanks

Answer (score 0):

As this commit suggests:
https://github.com/lowewenzel/bet/commit/c8b8e3706a9dcb5353237c7a4152c0207e882a21

Create a file backend/.env

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=4040
JWT_SECRET=EXAMPLE
COOKIE_SECRET=EXAMPLE
SESSION_SECRET=EXAMPLE
MONGO_HOST=mongodb://localhost:27017/bet
MONGO_PORT=27017
```

While it might be a bit sloppy to not have it documented, at least it's understandable because you never want your .env files to be committed to your git repo (because it contains secrets).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to working with a code found on github

1. Always look for the node_modules folder(dependencies), because node modules get too big in size and people never want such a big file to be committed to their repo.

   ```
   npm -i
   ```
2. Have a look in its package.json file to find traces that project uses .env files or you need to have a look in code like connection strings, password key,api keys (values which people don't want to be exposed on Github!!) if it uses .env files

then `locally prepare a .env file with appropriate key-values`